# How to realize password retry counter with Jetpack Compose?

Tags: android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack

I would like to count the attempts entering the PIN and show notifications accordingly:

```
val remainingPinCounter = remember { mutableStateOf(3) }
//
if(pinState == WRONG_PIN) {
    remainingPinCounter.value--
    showWrongPinNotification(remainingPinCounter)
}

@Composable
private fun showWrongPinNotification(retries: MutableStateOf<Int>){
    if(retries.value > 0) Log.d("TAG", "Remaining Retries := $retries.value)
    else Log.d("TAG", "All $retries.value attempts failed!)
    //..
}
```

But the `showWrongPinNotification()` is called continously with increasing `remainingPinCounter` to **-infinity** , although I decrement it via `pinState == WRONG_PIN` only?! I guess the state `WRONG_PIN` is not changing and thus constantly calling `showWrongPinNotification` with decremented values?

It worked properly without **remeber** ->`val remainingPinCounter = 3`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if(pinState == WRONG_PIN) {
    remainingPinCounter.value--
    showWrongPinNotification(remainingPinCounter)
}
```

might be the infinite recompositions if you don't change `pinState` before next recomposition. If that's the case on each recomposition conditional block is invoked and value of `remainingPinCounter` changed constantly.

```
LaunchedEffect(pinState) {
    if(pinState == WRONG_PIN) {
        remainingPinCounter.value--
        showWrongPinNotification(remainingPinCounter)
    }
}
```

Other option is to decrease it only once using LaunchedEffect as